# Load images from folder into HTML page for display in gallery/album automatically as they are added to folder

Tags: javascript, php, html, automation, gallery

I have recently found and purchased a beautiful HTML5 Ajax template that includes a gallery section in the main content section of the page that looks like this:

```
<!-- Main Content -->
```

```
<div class="ajax-inserted-content">

    <!-- Section Gallery -->
    <section class="section gallery grid layout-4-col">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <!-- Gallery Item -->
                <div class="col-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">

                    <div class="gallery-item">
                        <div class="gallery-img">
                            <img data-lazy-image
                                 src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAzIDIiPjwvc3ZnPg=="
                                 data-src="img/demo-img-2.jpg" alt="Demo img">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <!-- /Gallery Item -->
```

Now, I can add images manually to the gallery and in the HTML file by copy/pasting the "Gallery Item" sections and adding the image src and so on, but I have whole folders full of images (all .jpg but with different and various titles) so this is not an option.

About a decade ago I had a Flash website that had a gallery that was populated from folders using - as far as I can remember - an XML/PHP combination. There was no need to edit the actual HTML document. I expected there to be a (simple) PHP/XML option with this modern photography template, but alas. The developer of the template can't help me out either so now I'm stuck with a beautiful but useless template if I can't get this proces of populating the galleries and albums automated.

Thus my questions are as follows:

1. is there a customisable tool (like a plugin?) that can automate this for me that I can install server side so I have a wysiwyg option to upload images (drag and drop, upload from folder, etc) and point to the HTML page/code/gallery section into which the images need to be displayed?
2. if option 1 is not available, then are there ready-made XML/JSON/PHP scripts available anywhere that will do the same with a minimal amount of coding for customisation (possibly with only the need to upload image files and edit an XML file to get the images displayed in the HTML gallery page properly)?
3. if option 1 and 2 are not possible, does anyone have a solution for this issue?

I know there are plenty of options out there and have found various and simple-looking  (PHP/JS) scripts and code that claim to do exactly this, but they all involve creating a simple HTML page and gallery from scratch. I have no idea how to customise all that code to work with my HTML/CSS/JS website...

So I'm very much hoping that your suggestions will give me a budget-friendly solution, or I will have to buy me a totally new template that has the automated gallery scripts built-in

Comment: You are asking multiple questions in one, so your question may end up [closed](/help/closed-questions). Read [ask].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The PHP way**

a PHP loop generated from `scadir()` would make this pretty easy.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

I'm assuming the `src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PH...` is a placeholder, the same for each image

```
<div class="ajax-inserted-content">
  <!-- Section Gallery -->
  <section class="section gallery grid layout-4-col">
   <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
     <?php
        $imagesPath = '/imgportfolio/';
        // this is assuming your website has a folder at the document-root level called 'portfolio-images'.
        // document-root means where your top level index.html (or index.php) is.
        $dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .  $imagesPath; 
        $files = scandir($dir);
        $exts = ['png','jpg','jpeg','gif','bmp','webp'];
        foreach ($files as $file) {
          if ($file === '..' || $file === '.') continue;  
          $ext = explode(".", $file);
          $ext = strToLower($ext[count($ext)-1]);
          if (!in_array($ext, $exts)) continue; // if not a valid image file, skip 
     ?>
  <div class="col-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
     <div class="gallery-item">
       <div class="gallery-img">
         <img data-svg="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAzIDIiPjwvc3ZnPg==" src="<?php echo $imagesPath . $file;?>" alt="Demo img">

         <!-- <img data-lazy-image src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAzIDIiPjwvc3ZnPg==" data-src="<?php echo $imagesPath . $file;?>" alt="Demo img"> -->
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
        
    <?php }?>
```

Also, for testing (if you suspect PHP errors,) you can put this at the top of your page

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```

---

**The (I don't want to use) PHP Way**

There are some experimental features out there for reading a filesystem using javascript. For the most part they're not embraced by all modern browsers (IE doesn't allow them at all), and the complexity they introduce is more than you probably want to deal with.

However, in the past I have used this trick to create a simple portfolio. It requires your (re)naming your images to be in a predictable numeric sequence like

```
1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg, 4.jpg, 5.jpg, 6.jpg, 7.jpg, etc...
```

In your case the implementation would look like this:

```
<div class="ajax-inserted-content">
    <section class="section gallery grid layout-4-col">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row" id='gallery-items'>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
<script>
function doPortItem(n) {
    let img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = './imgportfolio/' + n + '.jpg';
    img.addEventListener('load', () => {
        let div = `<div class="col-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
     <div class="gallery-item">
       <div class="gallery-img">
         <img data-lazy-image data-src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAzIDIiPjwvc3ZnPg==" src="${img.src}" alt="Demo img"> 
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>`;
        document.querySelector('#gallery-items').innerHTML += div;
        doPortItem(++n)
    })
}
doPortItem(1)
</script>
```

**Notes** - Files must start with 1.jpg and have to be sequential. It loops through the numbers until it finds a X.jpg that doesn't exist, then it stops. Also, this looks for a folder called `imgportfolio` in the same directory as the `.html` file. Tested and works!

Comment: Yes, the data-lazy-image src seems to be a placeholder: it is the same in every gallery item. So do I need to copy/paste your code into a document, call it "gallery.php" and then refer to it in the html of the page? If so, what code do I need to place into the html? Or do I copy/paste this code straight into the main content section of the html gallery page? I really do need a step-by-step instruction, sorry to say...

Comment: Ok, i actually missed something, so I updated my answer. Yes, this needs to be in a php page (gallery.php). Yes, you should be able to just copy replace. Note my inline comments about the scandir directory - and also obviously the HTML you posted isn't the whole page :).

Comment: Ok, so I created an imgportfolio.php file, placed it in root and edited the dir to "imgportfolio", which is the image folder in the root folder where the index.html and other html files like the portfolio.html are also. Before creating the separate php file I tried copy/pasting your php code into the portfolio.html main content section but it will then only show the placeholder and nothing else... So now I have the portfolio.html, the imgportfolio folder and the imgportfolio.php all in the root folder. What code should I add to portfolio.html to call on the imgportfolio.php?

Comment: If I understand you, there's just one page. portfolio.php, which is this page (the portfolio page that came with your template change to a `.php`). If you put it in and only see the placeholder, view-source and look at what image it is putting in there. There' going to be something odd about the image path. I updated my answer, please use the new code and change the $imagesPath to be whatever folder your portfolio images are in. It should start with `/` and and with `/` and be like the example or `/assets/img/portfolio/` or whatever yours is

Comment: If I add your php code to the portfolio.html and save as portfolio.php the page will not display in browser (Chrome just gives me white page with the code) so no way to test anything. Like I said before, I have the portfolio.html (webpage, one of many html documents that are linked to in menu's from index.html) and the folders with the images (for the portfolio this is "imgportfolio"). If I add the php code to the portfolio.html and keep it as html, then no gallery, just a single placeholder is generated while rest of html code (header, footer, menu's, etc) works fine.

Comment: you need to keep it as .php for this to work. I just tested this code locally and it works. except the SVG didn't render... but that has nothing to do with the php code. For testing, can you update your `<img` tag like I just did in the updated answer? it gets rid of the SVG and lazy-loading. to troubleshoot, we need to get to the basics. Also, I added some PHP at the bottom of my answer to help troubleshoot PHP errors (which I don't think this is)

Comment: I can't make the html into a php file or I'll not be able to test it in the browser: I'm not a developer and have no local server or something like that running to be able to test these things other than through a regular browser like Chrome. I'm afraid there's just no way I am going to get this template functional. I'm sure your code works perfectly but I'm giving up on this template. Thanks so much for the effort though, I think many users will find your code and input  very useful.

Comment: Ok, I added to my answer a very rudimentary way to do this without PHP and without knowing how many images are in the folder (you can keep adding images and they'll get picked up). It's not the 'right' way to do this, but will work. Hoping to earn a shiny answer accepted :)

Comment: Yes, the JS works perfectly, gallery is populating nicely as long as the images are indeed numbered consecutively and in the format you specified.  Indeed not the "right" way to do it and thus not the solution I was hoping for to make this template usable, but it is a working solution :). Thanks again!